# Shortened excerpt function only working properly on posts that have excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following to shorten the excerpt if it exceeds a certain amount of characters, whilst also not cutting the last word.

```html
ob_start();
the_excerpt();
$excerpt = ob_get_clean();
  
 if (strlen($excerpt) < 200) {
      echo $excerpt;
        } else {
            $new = wordwrap($excerpt, 200);
            $new = explode("\n", $new);

            $new = $new[0] . '...';

            echo $new;
        }
```

The problem is that this only works if an excerpt is set, if not the excerpt only displays the first line or first sentence - see photo. I understand that the_excerpt pulls the_content if no excerpt is present, but do not understand why the wordwrap doesnt work properly when content is used instead of the excerpt?

[image: The first two images have no excerpt last one has]

Comment: I would try to use **get_the_excerpt** instead of the_excerpt. The function the_excerpt is just a wrapper. I can see that the excerpt only returns in your case 7 words, so I guess that somewhere else has been modified.

Comment: Why are you certain that this code is actually executing? @Alberto Marin's observation seems to indicate that this code is NOT running and the output you are seeing is from some other code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a slightly different way to shorten the excerpt and that worked. The other code was definitely working and only in the above example was it showing 7 words, the character count basically only worked until there was a line break and then it would cut the rest of the content off.

I have additionally added a "filter" to get rid of line html tags, so that there are no line breaks in the excerpt, since the clean output buffering removes the wpautop filter.

```html
<?php ob_start();
  the_excerpt();
  $excerpt = ob_get_clean();
  $excerpt = preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $excerpt);;
  ?>
  <?php 
  if ( strlen( $excerpt ) > 320 ) {

   $cut = substr( $excerpt, 0, 320 );
 
   $excerpt = substr( $cut, 0, strrpos( $cut, ' ' ) ) . '...';

   echo $excerpt;
  } else {
            echo $excerpt;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this experiment:

```
ob_start();
the_excerpt();
$excerpt = ob_get_clean();

if (strlen($excerpt) < 200) {
    echo $excerpt;
} else {
    $i = strpos($excerpt, ' ');
    $new = wordwrap($excerpt, 200);
    $new = explode("\n", $new);
    $j = count($new);
    $new = $new[0] . '...';
    echo "<div style=\"border:3px solid red;\">first space at $i<br>count is $j</div>";
    echo $new;
}
```

I think your code is correct. It seems the only way it can fail is wordwrap() cannot find any spaces or wordwrap() doesn't insert "\n" - neither of which seems reasonable but something isn't right. After reading Alberto Marin's comment I think the problem is your code is either not running or being completely replaced by an enclosing output buffer. In this case the red div will not appear.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me figure out if the code output was appearing on the page.